# WooCommerce Product Vendors Plugin Does not send email notifications to Vendor for new order received

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Product Vendors Version: 2.1.28 plugin for vendor management.

Currently, when a new order is received the notification is sent to Customer and Admin, but not sent to the Vendor Admin.

In my case, when the admin changes the order status, it doesn't send emails either. I need to send that notification email when an order is received.
Can this be achieved by creating a filter in functions.php or maybe by triggering product status change notification when the order is received?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I'm encountering the same.